# How to call function contents via another function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code

```
def pull_group_info
      # we want to store this section of information
      @groupinfo =  " name:\n
                    creditor_number,\n
                    iban,\n
                    company_invoices.from_date,\n
                    company_invoices.to_date,\n
                    rechnungsnummer,\n
                    company_invoices.r_number,\n
                    company_invoices.s_number:\n
                    companies.send_invoice_automatically:\n
                    companies.claim_netting:\n
                    company_invoices.total_cents:\n
                    rechnungsbetrag:\n
                    abrechnungsbetrag:\n
                    case_files.currency:\n
                    companies.vat_perspective:\n
                    companies.creditor_payout_by_case_file_invoice:"

    end

    def display_group_info
      # we want to display information that we have pulled
      @groupinfo
    end
```

And now I would like to be able to display this info later, but with a quick call back in another function, what is the best way to go about this? Example below of what I've tried.

```
 def query_for_****(_group_by, _companies_data)
      ''"
      SELECT
      distinct NAME,
      puts @groupinfo
      companies.data->>'creditor_number' as creditor_number,
      companies.data -> 'pay_to_bank_account' ->> 'iban' AS iban,
```

Comment: Idk, maybe you need to call the `pull_group_info` function first in order to initialize the `@groupinfo`.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend building SQL queries like this. But `@groupinfo` is just a simple string and the query is a string too, which means you can just use string interpolation:

```
def query_for_****(_group_by, _companies_data)
  "
  SELECT
  distinct NAME,
  #{@groupinfo}
  companies.data->>'creditor_number' as creditor_number,
  companies.data -> 'pay_to_bank_account' ->> 'iban' AS iban,
```

But again, you tagged your question with `ruby-on-rails` and you really should not build SQL statememts like that. I suggest reading in the Rails guides about the [ActiveRecord query language](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).